# about nl, br and security while working with textarea and mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting data from my textarea with the following code

```
$about_me=mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br($_POST['about_me']));
```

which 
1. Receives  data, using $_POST.
2. nl2br makes brakes so If I echo this code to user he will see if there were new lines.
3. mysql_real_escape_string to secure code from mysql injections before entering it to database.

So if I echo this code everything works fine.

But If I edit it again through textarea, php goes to mysql gets data, puts it to textarea and I see `<br>` signs...

How can I get rid of them while editing my text again in textarea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I get rid of them while editing my text again in textarea ?

Stop using `nl2br()`, of course. It's entirely wrong here.

---

You use `nl2br()` when you want to *output* data that contains linebreaks to HTML, not when you want to store it in the database. Store data unchanged, format it for viewing.

If you output it into a `<textarea>` you don't need to use it either, since textareas display linebreaks (whereas HTML in general does not). For the textarea you need `htmlspecialchars()`, but apparently this is already happening - otherwise you would not see literal `<br>` showing up.

Comment: Quite right. But maybe you could elaborate on where to use it.

Comment: @David: I thought *"do not use `nl2br()` here"* would be clear?

Comment: @David, if you use `nl2br()` on plain text, you are performing a *partial* conversion to HTML: you convert line feeds and leave everything else as is. That's not useful. Tomalak is just suggesting to store text exactly as typed by the user. You'll have time to make a *proper* conversion to HTML when you need to display the text as HTML.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
function br2nl($string){
  $return=eregi_replace('<br[[:space:]]*/?'.
    '[[:space:]]*>',chr(13).chr(10),$string);
  return $return;
}
?>
```

Use this while getting data from database and before printing into textarea .

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Check examples on this page

Comment: Sounds rather counterproductive to first convert the data with `nl2br()` and then use a function to remove the br tags just to get back to the initial situation.

Comment: Maybe there is some small peace of code which can solve my problem ? This one looks big I don't think that it is the best way to solve my problem